# Dependency requires non existenant subdependency maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, kotlin, gradle, groovy

I want to compile the sarosEclipse plugin myself: "https://github.com/saros-project/saros"

The problem is: `Could not find any version that matches javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:[1.3.5,2.0.0).`

As you can see the latest release is 1.3.2 "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.e4.core.di/1.7.700"

I think eclipse means "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.0.0"

I already tried to force a downgrade which leads to 6 failed gradle tests

I also tried to create a local maven repository, decompiled the Jakarta version, and renamed the packages. But I think I failed at this one.

Does anyone know how to override the dependency? I don't think it is possible because the Jakarta version uses other package names. Why has Eclipse no problems? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Based on the given version range it simply does not exist in that version in central: https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api  I don't know which repos you are using....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems like this version does not exist oát any repo. The only one I can find is the jakarta version. I think its an issue of the eclipse team. Any idea for an workaround?